# Zip file doesn't arrive when attached to email

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, zip

Im trying to zip up my sqlite files from my `documents directory` to send via mail using https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive.

```
    NSString *filePath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"app.sqlite"];
    NSString *filePath2 = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"app.sqlite-shm"];
    NSString *filePath3 = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"app.sqlite-wal"];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *archivePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@".zip"];
        //Zip up files
        ZipArchive *archiver = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
        [archiver CreateZipFile2:archivePath];
        [archiver addFileToZip:filePath newname:@"backUp.sqlite"]; 
        [archiver addFileToZip:filePath2 newname:@"backUp.sqlite-shm"]; 
        [archiver addFileToZip:filePath3 newname:@"backUp.sqlite-wal"]; 


        MFMailComposeViewController *mailView = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        if (mailView != nil) {


            mailView.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [mailView setSubject:@"Database"];
            //Attach zip file
            [mailView addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:archivePath] mimeType:@"application/zip" fileName:@"test.zip"];
            [mailView setMessageBody:@"Database attached" isHTML:NO];

            [self presentViewController:mailView animated:YES completion: NULL];

        }
```

The attachment appears in the email preview on the device but when it arrives with the recipient the attachment has vanished?

also tried this:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"app.sqlite"];
        NSString *filePath2 = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"app.sqlite-shm"];
        NSString *filePath3 = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"app.sqlite-wal"];

        DebugLog(@"DB path is: %@", filePath);
        NSError *error = nil;

        NSData *fileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:0UL error:&error];
        NSString* fileDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:fileData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];

        NSData *fileData2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath2 options:0UL error:&error];
        NSString* fileData2String = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:fileData2 encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];

        NSData *fileData3 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath3 options:0UL error:&error];
        NSString* fileData3String = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:fileData3 encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];

        if (error != nil) {
            DebugLog(@"Failed to read the file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            if (fileData == nil) {
                DebugLog(@"File data is nil");
            }
        }


        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *archivePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@".zip"];
        //Zip up documents directory
        ZipArchive *archiver = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
        [archiver CreateZipFile2:archivePath];
        [archiver addFileToZip:fileDataString newname:@"backUp.sqlite"]; 
        [archiver addFileToZip:fileData2String newname:@"backUp.sqlite-shm"];
        [archiver addFileToZip:fileData3String newname:@"backUp.sqlite-wal"]; 



        MFMailComposeViewController *mailView = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        if (mailView != nil) {


            mailView.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [mailView setSubject:@"Database"];
            //Attach zip file
            [mailView addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:archivePath] mimeType:@"application/zip" fileName:@"test.zip"];
            [mailView setMessageBody:@"Database attached" isHTML:NO];

            [self presentViewController:mailView animated:YES completion: NULL];

        }
```

same behaviour `zip` file does not arrive with email

Logging the `archivePath` gives me `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1D32A3AA-A431-46234-AE4B-ED944CA2D883F4/Documents.zip`

Comment: DO NOT create paths using `NSHomeDirectory()`. Such code will not work on iOS 8 devices. It was never correct for any iOS version (though it did work prior to iOS 8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically an email attachment doesn't arrive for one of two reasons:

1. The path you used to load the `NSData` resulted in the data being `nil`.
2. The file is too large to send via email.

You have several issues leading to problem one.

1. The path for the zip file is in a read-only folder - the root of your app's resource bundle.
2. Never use `NSHomeDirectory()` to create paths to folders in your app's sandbox. Things changed in iOS 8 and such paths won't work at all. Only use `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` with the proper folder reference such as `NSDocumentDirectory`.

To solve the first issue, change this:

```
NSString *archivePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@".zip"];
```

to something like:

```
NSString *archivePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SomeFiles.zip"];
```

It would be even better to store this temporary file in the caches folder (use `NSCachesDirectory` instead of `NSDocumentDirectory`). Then delete the file after sending the email.

Comment: Care to explain why this was down voted? What's wrong with the answer?

Comment: Wasn't my downvote.  Changing to `NSString *archivePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/afileNameHere.zip"]`;  creates the zip file.  The `/` being instrumental here maybe that had something to do with it? Thanks as always for your direction on this

Comment: Instead of using `stringByAppendingString` and providing the slash in the name, use `stringByAppendingPathComponent`. Like this: `NSString *archivePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"afileNameHere.zip"];`.

Comment: Ah will do, thanks again, accepted and upvoted to counter  that random downvote on your helpful answer as the person has not come back to explain